# No Sound in ASUS ZenBook UX431FL running 20.04

Tags: sound, kernel, asus

I cannot seem to work around this known issue. Audio doesn't work and I can't get it fixed.

I know there's a solution here: https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/1022579/

Can anyone guide me through this process? I'm new to linux and I don't really know where to put my hands. Thanks a lot!

kernel: 5.4.0-7625-generic

Comment: Wrong link above, CHECK THIS  https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/0bea4cc8383519f78f3f74caca7bdebdfb346d3b

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a reinstallation may help. But before you make bootable media and start the reinstallation, make sure that you have verified it with SHA256, SHA1, and MD5, so in that way, you won't end up with one that is corrupted!